# NgRx/Redux less duplicate code with more general reducers

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, angular-ngrx-data

I'm building an application where I have different pages with lists of movies. E.g. **search page** (movies by search), **actor's page** (movies by actor), **genre's page** (movies by genre). The thing is all of them share the same basic functionality - load a list of movies by some criteria.
I have a reducer for storing movies entities once something is loaded. But the problem is I have to create a separate reducer for each page type to save relevant movie ids to display.

Originally, I simply implemented all of those pages from scratch while duplicating a lot of code - separate actions, effects, reducers for each page. Now I feel that it's quite ugly and could be done in a neater way.

I already have a well-generalised ***queryMovies*** function in my service that queries movies by the options parameter.

Could you suggest any good way of organising such code?

EDIT:

Since this post was deleted, I cannot comment or reply (only edit). So I'm adding this link as part of an edit: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-ngrx-data

And I think this is a *great* question and would like to see more of a discussion on appropriate architectures/patterns for ngRx.

Comment: *Could you suggest any good way of organising such code?* This alone makes this question both too broad, and primarily opinion based. Off topic for SO.